# Caveats against using timestamp values for dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar

I have been using 'date as a long' (getTime() / +) all the time when operating on dates in client side Javascript, for comparison, evaluation and also for transport of date from (not to) our Java server side to client side Javascript.
It saved me from the headache of browser misbehaviour in date handling.

But recently this practice was questioned and I still haven't got any reason why I should use string dates instead. Are there any problems in this usage of timestamps that I am unable to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any problem when your server side is Java.

Only thing I can add is - it is handy to use a javascript library like `moment.js` on client side. `moment.js` is a rich date handling library. Go for it if you have to do lot of date manipulations, display in different formats or read date from user.

Answer (score 0):

JS timestamps are milliseconds-since-the-epoch. Most server systems (unless you're dealing with node.js) use plain seconds-since-the-epoch. Any JS timestamp representing "now"-type dates are therefore WAY past the size limits of a normal 32bit signed unix timestamp, and will be truncated/corrupted.

Sending a string avoids this, because pretty much any decent system can accept a date string and convert it back into its own native time system, whereas taking a corrupted truncated int is just a matter of garbage-in, garbage-out.

Of course, if your server-side systems are aware they'll be receiving a JS timestamp, they can accept as a string, then do some basic truncation to lop off the milliseconds component, leaving them with a normal seconds-based timetamp string that can be converted to an int.

Comment: In the question NikhilWanpal has already indicated server side is Java. Therefore there should not be any truncation problem with the milliseconds date.

Comment: I am only receiving timestamps in client side javascript, to avoid the browser specific issues. To send dates, I am using string representation in formats understood by our server.